# In debug mode, how to see the text property of a UITextField?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, debugging, uitextfield

I am stepping through code in a `UITextField`, but I don't see where it shows what the text currently is (it should be `@"hi"`). Where would I find this value?

[image]

Comment: You could always temporarily set up a NSString *test = yourTextfield.text

Comment: Use `po textField.text` in the debugger console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: (in console where debug messages are)
Type this: po textField.text

Comment: po ->print object (briefly explained), try to type 'help' to get info about commands that are possible.